# prevent java from multiple openings of the same window-JFrame

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

for example i create this on click

```
//this creates autor object with default constructor properties defined in autor class
menuAutor.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                autor Autor = new autor("Autor");
            }
        });
```

so object named Autor is created, and when i click again on the button, it pops up again the same Autor object.. how can prevent opening the same window if one is already opened?

EDIT: FINALY A SOLUTION! 
After lots of thinking about this.. i made my solution...
default value for **autorOpen="no"** i declaired at the beginning of my class, just to let you know because its not visible in code below, the solution itself:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if(autorOpen=="no") {
                autor Autor = new autor("Autor");
                autorOpen = "yes";
                Autor.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
                    {
                        autorOpen = "no";
                    }
                });
                }
                else 
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Demo notice... you can't open that window again.. its opened already!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
            }
        });
```

Comment: is the Autor subclass of JFrame?

Comment: `boolean open = false; ... if(!open) { open = true; autor Autor = ... }`. Your naming convention is quite weird.

Comment: @khachik That won't work if `autor` can close itself.

Comment: About your implementation of my idea: whoa that's messy. 1) Use a boolean if you want to use yes/no. 2) You should really store the actual `autor` object. What if the user closes the window? `autorOpen` will still be true. If you stored the actual object, you can say `if (myAutor == null || myAutor.isOpen() == false) myAutor = new autor()`

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt, I didn't mention where to define `open` ;)

Comment: yes ... you are right, i will edit my solution soon...

Comment: @khachik You did, as you wrote `open = true;`, which means it's definitely not part of the object `autor`.

Comment: You should also re-open or change focus to the already open window instead of an error message.  The user clicked that button because they wanted to see the window after all.

Comment: @Thomas that error message is just for demonstation purpose....

Comment: @ИгорРајачић, instead of  `autorOpen.equals("no")==true` write `autorOpen.equals("no")` and instead of string use boolean.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt, How "globally" means "in autor"? It can be a private field of `autor`, or a field in the controller. Your point that autor can close itself doesn't change anything, because you can add a listener to `autor` which can set a boolean flag outside of `autor`.

Comment: that is not solution. @khachik it worked autorOpen.equals("no")==true
this worked perfectly. but i can't change variable when windows closes, so i have to implement window listener to do the job correctly. as i said i will reupload my code when im done. thanks anyway. p.s if you make working example. i will give you credit. only working solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Edited my question... you can find my solution to this problem there... its tested, and it works properly as it should. If any of you have some better method of doing this, feel free to paste your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the variable a little bit more globally, and check whether it exists before creating a new one.

Comment: sounds interesting will check it out. how i didn't taught of that before.. lol... but i will wait for more answers, maybe someone has different solution.

Comment: I'm guessing that some might say things about using a boolean on a more global scope... But in that case you might just as well store the entire object there, 'cause it allows you to check whether it's still active.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider implementing Autor as a singleton class (to ensure only one is ever instantiated).

```
public class Autor {

private static Autor instance = null;

//Must be protected or private, get a reference to this class with getInstance().
protected Autor() {
}


/**
* Returns reference to this class - use in place of constructor
*/
public static Autor getInstance() {
if(instance == null) {
instance = new Autor();
}
return instance;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean flag to indicate if the dialog is up or not. Set it to true if the dialog is popped up, and set it to false when you close that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating something with 'new' on each click, you'll get a new window each time.  One solution is to create autor before any clicks happen, then have the event move it from hidden to visible.